# Run index.html outside the webpack-server dist folder (development mode)

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, reload

Apart from the dist folder, I have another folder called demo. and this demo folder contains the index.html file.

When I run demo / index.html with dev server, I can't find the files in the dist folder.

folder structure;

```
/ demo
  - index.html
/ dist
 - bundle.js
/ src 
 - index.js
```

webpack.dev.js :

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  mode: 'development',
  devServer: {
    open: true,
    hot: true,
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, './demo'),
    port: 9000,
  },
 ...
```

I want to refresh the browser every time I make a change in the src folder.